# ImageHorizonLibrary: [ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

I've got the error `[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.` when launching a robotframework script, it uses two libraries sikuli and ImageHorizonLibrary that I use in an automated test.
I found that when I do not use the ImageHorizonLibrary a script that did not need it works flawlessly.I searched a lot but could not find an answer or an alternative to ImageHorizonLibrary.
Note that I'm new to automated tests and robotframework and I run my tests on mint 20.3 .

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to debug the execution. Start robot with the option `--loglevel TRACE` so you can see each step. Also, be aware that ImageHorizonLibrary may be outdated regarding Python version or Robot Framework versions.

Comment: I tried all you've suggested but nothing else appear than my error, I have tried it on windows and it works, but I need to run it on linux.